# Aparecer mensagem quando passo o rato

Tags: html

Tenho a seguinte instrução

```
<li> <a href='equipas\ecl\ecl.html'>  ECL title="Mensagem"  </a>



       </li>
```

Só que nada acontece, a palavra "Mensagem" não parece

Comment: Mas "mensagem" faz parte do conteúdo do seu elemento, ele deve aparecer com ou sem a interação com o rato. Consegue elaborar um [mcve]? Da forma atual que está sua pergunta parece que você não colocou o problema por completo.

Comment: não vai aparecer, title deve estar dentro da tag e não no conteúdo, tente `<a title="Mensgem"`

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim para ver se funciona, comigo funcionou sem qualquer problema. Espero que consiga ajudar.

```html
<a title="Mensagem" href='equipas\ecl\ecl.html'> ECL title="Mensagem" </a>
```